# Spring Security, JSP Tag Lib Error

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, spring-security

I want to include spring security tag in my JSP file (means in JSP taglib scriptlet) , so I have added following line in my JSP 
taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" (in JSP tag lib)

but i am getting following error
home.jsp:2:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

works for me, with these

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
        </dependency>
```

where spring.security.version = 3.1.4.RELEASE.

And make sure you have included the correct jst jar.

Comment: Nope it did not work for me :( but thanks for your suggestion and one more thing i am using webLogic server and also do we need to do any change in web.xml file

Comment: I have found other way round it is not a good way but any how it is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Gradle, add to build.gradle

```
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:$springSecurityVersion"
```

or

```
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.2.0.RELEASE"
```

or your version

Answer (score 1):

I have found other way round it is not a good way but any how it is working for me,I have copied all the .class to /WEB-INF/class and copied the .tld file into /WEB-INF and when I was deploying the project i was using <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" % but after deploying project i have changed my taglib element to @ taglib prefix="sec" uri="/WEB-INF/security.tld" and that used spring security tags and it is working fine i know it is not a good way but right i want to learn spring so it worked for me :)